# Remove Mail Applet from Toolbar in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: uninstall, mail, applet

I am trying to find out how to remove the Thunderbird Mail Applet from the top right corner of the toolbar in Ubuntu 14.04 I have already tried going to Thunderbird-Add-ons manager - Extensions and have disabled Messaging Menu and Unity Launcher integration 1.3.1 But this has not removed the mail applet from the toolbar

Answer (score 0):

In Thunderbird,goto menu "Edit", "Preferences", then select the "Advanced" section and click on "Config. Editor

find:

```
extensions.messagingmenu.enabled
```

and set it to false.
Close your session and re-open it or reboot

[image: Advanced settings]

Comment: I have had a look through the advanced section as suggested looking for extensions.messaging.enabled - I do not have / see any such line under extensions - the nearest match I could see saying anything about 'messagingmenu' was the following;   extensions.xpiState;{"app-global":{"messagingmenu@mozilla.com":{"d":"/usr/lib/thunderbird/extensions/messagingmenu@mozilla.com.xpi","e":false,"v":".................. my Thunderbird version is 38.5.1 running on Ubuntu 14.04